# Making the column of the DataTable to accept only numeric values

Tags: c#

There is a class called `DisplayTable`. Later binding to some observation Collection and then populating the values to the `datatable`.

I need the value column of the table should accept only integers, decimals, double.

```
public class DisplayTable
{
    public string AnalyteName { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"0-9+(.)", ErrorMessage="This field accept Only numeric values")]
    public float ReferenceValue { get; set; }

}


//Binding the class to Collection

public ObservableCollection<DisplayTable> list { get; set; }

// creating an istance to the class
DisplayTable d = new DisplayTable();

d.AnalyteName ="c"
d.Units= "mg"

this.list.Add(d)

  table.Columns.Add("Analyte Name");
  table.Columns.Add("Units");

 table.Columns.Add("Value");


      foreach (var item in this.list)
      {
          drn = table.NewRow();
          int col = 0;
          drn[col] = item.AnalyteName ;
          drn[col + 1] = item.Units;
          drn[col + 2] = item.ReferenceValue;
          table.Rows.Add(drn);
          table.AcceptChanges();
     }
   dataGrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`DataColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2) have a data type, exposed through it's [`DataType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2) property.
The `Add` method of the [`DataColumnCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) have several overloads, some of which allows you to specify the data type of the column.
The overload you are currently using uses the default data type, which is a string.
If you want to specify a different data type, use another overload:

```
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(decimal));
```

However, you are interested in a column that can hold multiple data types - integers, decimals doubles and floats - and those data types are not interchangeable.

I've chosen [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) data type since it is more accurate then a `double`, however since there is no implicit conversion between the other floating points data types ([`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float), [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double)) and `decimal` you will have to explicitly cast the value to `decimal` when setting the cell value:

```
  foreach (var item in this.list)
  {
      drn = table.NewRow();
      int col = 0;
      drn[col] = item.AnalyteName ;
      drn[col + 1] = item.Units;
      drn[col + 2] = (decimal) item.ReferenceValue;
      table.Rows.Add(drn);
      table.AcceptChanges();
 }
```